# View an item without republishing everything?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm getting this error when trying to view a Sitecore item based on a template that contains nothing but one sublayout played in a placeholder in another layout. I can place the sublayout in other sublayouts and view it on another item, and I can *preview* the item, but when I go to view that item I get this:

> The layout for the requested document
>   was not found.
>
> [blah blah blah]
>
> Requested Layout: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
>
> [blah blah blah some more]

The only way I've found to view the new item is to do a "Publish Site" from the Publish tab. Is there a way to get that one item working without republishing everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish the sublayout in question. Ribbon >> Publish Group >> Publish command drop down arrow >> publish item.

Based on your question, you should consider reviewing documentation for Content and Presentaiton on the Sitecore Developer Network at sdn.sitecore.net.